# Internal Energy of Water During Vaporization

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, temperature, terminology

This is a dumb question, but I am pretty certain that water vapour has higher energy than water as you do work in raising the intermolecular potential energy. However, water vapour molecules at 100$^{\circ}$C have the same kinetic energy as water at 100$^{\circ}$C and since internal energy for an ideal gas is only its kinetic energy, while the internal energy of a liquid is its potential + kinetic energy, does it mean that water has higher internal energy than its gas state?

Comment: @RogerVadim I think this can be understood by thinking intermolecular potential energy of the liquid as negative. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, this is a good way to see it.